# precision , recall , f score when y_pred & y_true have different sizes

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, precision, precision-recall

I have two lists:
"A" is a list of lists, each item containing list of predicted tags
"B" is a list of lists, each item containing true tags

I'm trying to calculate precision, recall, f score using scikit-learn in iteration, A[i] compared to B[i] but it says

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:[3, 2]

I found some similar topics, but there was no answer [Computing precision and recall for two sets of keywords in NLTK and Scikit for sets of different sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621442/computing-precision-and-recall-for-two-sets-of-keywords-in-nltk-and-scikit-for-s)

Comment: are you passing the `average` argument in `precision_score()` or `recall_score()` as [described here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) for multilabel classification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `y_true` and `y_pred` size() must remain same for precision and recall. The size of `y_true[i]` and `y_pred[i]` may differ. Check the documentation for [`precision_score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) and [`recall_score()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html#sklearn.metrics.recall_score). Note that you need to pass a valid value to `average` argument in those methods.

Also check [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification) for more information about the multilabel classification scoring techniques.

**Edit**: Added some code taking your example data from comment.

First you need to one-hot encode your `y_true` and `y_pred` for all available labels in your data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, precision_score

A=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f','g']]
B=[['a','b'],['d','f','g']]

multibinarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()

A_new = multi.fit(A).transform(A)
B_new = multi.transform(B)

#average = 'valid strategy for multilabel
precision_score(A_new,B_new,average='samples')
#output -> 1.0
recall_score(A_new, B_new, average='samples')
#output -> 0.70833333333333326
```

Answer (score 0):

When we compute these metrics, we compare the actual values with the predicted values. So, if your test set has 10 data points, there should be 10 predictions coming from your model.

**TL;DR**
A[i] needs to be dimensionally consistent with B[i].

Can edit my answer to be more precise if you include examples of how the data looks like!

Comment: well my data is like A=[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f','g']]  and B=[['a','b'],['d','f','g']] , B items are predicted tags for A items, precision,recall and fscore formula is such that they can be calculated even two sets are not the same size

Comment: predictions and ground truths have a 1:1 mapping as far as I am aware...not sure what your use case is

Comment: Tag prediction in question answering systems, not there is no mapping I think